# SQLite - group by month based on UNIX timestamp

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a problem using SQLite3 with Room (v2.2.5) in Android.
I'm storing timestamps for some logs using UNIX timestamp in miliseconds. When I try to query them and group them by months, I get this strange error, where August and September are represented with 0 (they should be 8 and 9).

This is the query in EventLogDao:

```
@Query("""SELECT strftime('%m', date(timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch')) as month, COUNT(*) as count
                FROM ${EventLog.TABLE_NAME} 
                GROUP BY month""")
abstract fun getAllSortedByTimestamp(): Single<List<TempHolder>>
```

Here is the output I get. If I try to count instances by months it all works normally, just the number of the month for August and September is wrong.

[image]

Comment: `If I try to count` ... the query you posted doesn't actually select any aggregates.  Can you include the actual query?

Comment: Is the month an integer or string in TempHolder?

Comment: Also you can use just `strftime('%m', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch')`, no need for `date()` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I suspect is happening:

`strftime('%m', ...)` returns two-character-long **strings** like `'01'`, `'02'`, ... `'08'`, `'09'`, ... `'12'`. Your ORM is taking these strings and converting them to **integers** to store in this `TempHolder` class. Whatever conversion routine it's using looks at the leading `'0'` character present in 9 of the strings, decides that means those are base-8 octal constants, and converts accordingly. `08` and `09` are of course invalid octal numbers, but instead of raising an exception, the conversion code treats them as 0's.

I bet if you change your query to

```
@Query("""SELECT cast(strftime('%m', timestamp / 1000, 'unixepoch') as integer) as month,
                 COUNT(*) as count
          FROM ${EventLog.TABLE_NAME} 
          GROUP BY month""")
```

you'll get the expected results.